# How to find out GET request type from GraphQL in ASP.NET Core Web API with C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, graphql, asp.net-core-webapi

Working with ASP.NET Core Web API and C#. I'm using grapql to expose API endpoints.

All the requests in graphql are `POST` type. How can we identify if it is fetch (`GET`) type?

Tried to http request type to differentiate whether request belongs to GET or POST.

Comment: A singe http POST can contain one or more queries and/or one or more mutations. An http GET is only used to introspect the schema. What are you actually asking? Whether or not the POST is actually changing data?